# Getting the error Error:BrokenCount>0

Tags: apt, package-management

I am getting the following error in the top menu bar:

> An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right click
>   menu or apt-get in a terminal to see what is wrong.  The error message
>   was: "Error: BrokenCount>0". This usually means that your installed
>   packages have unmet dependencies.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo  apt install -f`. It should fix all of your broken packages. It usually deletes them, so make sure that it isn't deleting any packages that you need before you confirm the fix.